# Is $X_n=O_p(1)$ defined on same probability space?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

"$X_n$'s are bounded in probability" means "for every $\epsilon >0$ $\exists M_{\epsilon}$ such that   $P(|X_n|>M_{\epsilon})<\epsilon$ $\forall n\geq1$ i.e. a single  $M_{\epsilon}$ will work for all $n$. Now does that mean $X_n$ must be defined on the same probability space(like a.s./in probability convergence)? The same question arises(at least from my mind) when we say $\{X_n\}$ is *uniformly integrable*.

As when we say $X_n$ converges in distri. to $X$ all I am concerned about is their distri. function $\{F_n\}$. Thus if I know $F_n$ I can figure out whether $X_n=O_p(1)$ or not. Thus can I replace $P$ by $P_n$ in the definition of *bounded in probability* similarly in *uniformly integrable*?

As I've just started learning probability theory my concept is not quite clear regarding these. Would you please clarify my query/conceptual understanding? Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct -- the concept of boundedness in probability does not require all the $X_n$'s to be defined on the same probability space, because the concept concerns the distribution of each $X_n$. Similarly the concept of uniform integrability makes sense even if the $X_n$'s live on different spaces.

Only concepts that refer to pointwise behavior of the $X_n$'s (such as the sum of random variables, or the limsup of a sequence of RVs) absolutely require everything to be defined on the same space.

Comment: Or simply the *almost sure convergence* of the sequence $(X_n)$.

Comment: @grand_chat Thank you!